# Search within an array

Tags: php

I have an array where I want to search if there is certain information.

In case it exists I want to save all the data in variables

I am trying to do it with in_array but I can't find the information.The search I need to do with coords.
If it exists "60:58" in array I save the 3 values ​​in variables.

How could I get it? Thanks a lot of!!

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["coords"]=>
    string(5) "60:58"
    ["city"]=>
    string(5) "spain"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "player"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
    ["coords"]=>
    string(5) "60:59"
    ["city"]=>
    string(5) "spain"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "player"
 }
}
```

Comment: I suggest using array filter with a custom callback function so you can work with your object structure. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: `in_array` can't do it because it's an array of objects. So you'd have to iterate the array yourself, access the `coords` property on each and when you find a match, create your variables (although this seems a bit of an overkill to me, you could directly use the properties of the object).

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out everything that does not meet your criteria.  Then you either have an empty array or one or more objects matching the criteria.  I use `reset` to get the first if there are more than one:

```
$find = '60:58';
$result = reset(array_filter($array, function($v) use($find) { return $v->coords == $find; }));
```

If there is only one or you only require one, then you can index on `coords`.  If not found then this will generate a notice so check if it exist (this requires PHP >= 7 since we are using objects):

```
$result = array_column($array, null, 'coords')[$find];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = [];

$a[] = (object)[
    'coords' => '60:58'
];

$a[] = (object)[
    'coords' => '13:37'
];


$index = array_search('60:58', array_column($a, 'coords'));

if($index === false) {
    // not found
} else {
    $var = $a[$index];
    var_dump($var);
}
```

Comment: Add some description.  And `array_column` only works on objects in PHP 7.

Answer (score -1):

you have to loop over the array of objects and check if coords match with the value you want